# Inserting in files

Tags: php, html, css, file

When I click on "Comment", it is not opening the new file $cname.txt hence not able to insert values in file and therefore nothing is posted. I want that cname and comment to be posted when the user clicks submit? Here is my code:

```
 <?php
 $name="";
 /*print_r($_POST);*/
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
      global $name;
      $name=$_POST['name']; 
      $query=$_POST['query'];
      $my_query="My query";
     /* $files=fopen("$name.txt","w");
      fclose($files); */
      $po="$name <br> $my_query:$query \n";
      $myfile=fopen("posts.txt","a+");
      fwrite($myfile,$po);
      fclose($myfile);
 }
      $mypost=fopen("posts.txt","r");
        while($line = fgets($mypost)) {
        echo '<form class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey w3-text-blue w3-margin">
        <div class="w3-row w3-section">
        <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o" style="font-size:30px"></i></div>
        <div class="w3-rest">
        <p class="w3-input w3-border"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>'.$line; echo '</p>
    </div>
</div>
    <p>comments</p>
    <form method="post" action="' .htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); echo '">
    Name:<textarea name="cname" rows="1" cols="4"></textarea><textarea name="comment" rows="1" cols="60"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submits" value="Comment" class="w3-button w3-section w3-blue w3-ripple">
    </form>
    ' ; }
    $cname="";
    if(isset($_POST['submits'])) {
          global $cname;
          $cname=$_POST['cname']; 
          $comment=$_POST['comment'];
          $pos="$cname <br> $comment \n";
          $myfiles=fopen("$cname.txt","a+");
          fwrite($myfiles,$pos);
          fclose($myfiles);
          $myposts=fopen("$cname.txt","r");
          while($lines = fgets($myposts)) {
              echo $lines;
              }

    }'
    </form>'
    ;
      ?>
```

Comment: Try this $myfiles=fopen("{$cname}.txt","a+");

Comment: Using user-supplied data to determine your filename is, in a word, dangerous. Please filter your inputs.

Comment: I would also remove the additional spaces around the action.

Comment: @Philip what can be used.

Comment: Start here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: @DeepakKumarTP nothing happened.

Comment: Also check that your web server has file system permissions to write the file.

Comment: @Philip It has permission to write the file, I have checked it with a simple example.

Comment: Whats with all the syntax errors in the above code?

Comment: There's no syntax error actually it's a part of code... wait I will upload complete code.

Comment: See it once again @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
```

Comment: Actually I have opened <?php earlier than in between some HTML contents which is echoed therefore I didn't use that

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48005774/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.